# window.screenX is being calculated using all monitors, how can I get the x position of the window in the current monitor

Tags: javascript

The following code gets some properties of the monitor, window size and position. My issue is that `window.screenX` is being calculated by the wrong monitor.

As I have three monitors, if I put the window to the left of my left monitor it returns around -1920px as it is using the middle monitor as a center point, I want this to return zero. Is there any way to return a windows X position based on the *current* monitor that the window is in?

```js
let windowWidth
let windowHeight
let screenX
let screenY
let monitorWidth
let monitorHeight

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  onResize()
});

setInterval(() => {
  onResize()
}, 1000)

function onResize() {
  windowWidth = window.innerWidth
  windowHeight = window.innerHeight
  screenX = window.screenX
  screenY = window.screenY
  monitorWidth = window.screen.availWidth
  monitorHeight = window.screen.availHeight

  document.getElementById("windowWidth").innerHTML = 'windowWidth : ' + windowWidth;
  document.getElementById("windowHeight").innerHTML = 'windowHeight : ' + windowHeight;
  document.getElementById("screenX").innerHTML = 'screenX : ' + screenX;
  document.getElementById("screenY").innerHTML = 'screenY : ' + screenY;
  document.getElementById("monitorWidth").innerHTML = 'monitorWidth : ' + monitorWidth;
  document.getElementById("monitorHeight").innerHTML = 'monitorHeight : ' + monitorHeight;
}
```

```html
<div id="windowWidth"></div>
<div id="windowHeight"></div>
<div id="screenX"></div>
<div id="screenY"></div>
<div id="monitorWidth"></div>
<div id="monitorHeight"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `window.innerWidth`? Also, don't use `innerHTML` when you aren't working with strings that need to be parsed as HTML as `innerHTML` has security and performance implications. Instead use `.textContent`.

Comment: I need the x position of the window relative to the monitor. The innerHTML is just for debugging purposes to show the data.

Answer (score -2):

Use CSS for viewport adjustements - no need for javascript.

Example:

```
/* IF VIEWPORT IS SMALLER THAN 510 PX */
@media only screen and (max-width : 510px) {
div.this_wrapper{
max-width: 320px;
}
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with css or responsiveness. I need the x position of the browser window relative to the current monitor that the window is in.